# Storyboard.Completed Event Handler Preventing Code From Executing

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, eventhandler

I am trying to create a simulation program that animates based on the user's input.  I am running into an error when I try and create an eventhandler for mystoryboard.completed event.  I have read numerous different API articles and forum posts on eventhandling and storyboards but I can't seem to find the cause of my error.

My code compiles and the window displays but anything after the line where I set up the eventhandler doesn't get executed.  My MainWindow where I set everything up is shown below.

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            titleTextBlock.Text = "MainWindow()";
            //this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mainSystem = new BalanceSystem(3);
            leftBlock = new SystemComponents.Block(0, 100, 150, 100, mainSystem);
            rightBlock = new SystemComponents.Block(1, 100, 150, 100, mainSystem);
            balanceBeam = new SystemComponents.Bar(0, 0, 250, 150, 100, mainSystem);
            mainSystem.addComponent(leftBlock, leftWeight);
            mainSystem.addComponent(rightBlock, rightWeight);
            mainSystem.addComponent(balanceBeam, balanceBar);

            titleTextBlock.Text = "LOADED";
        }
```

The constructor for "BalanceSystem" is when things start to go wrong.  It steps into the constructor shown below:

```
public BalanceSystem(int count)
{
    componentCount = count;
    masterTimeline = new MovementTimeline(1);
}
```

After entering the constructor for "BalanceSystem" it moves on to the constructor for my custome class "MovementTimeline".  The line that breaks everything is the creation and subscription of the eventhandler for masterStoryboard.Completed.

```
class MovementTimeline
{
    private Storyboard masterStoryboard;
    private Duration systemDuration;

    public MovementTimeline(int totalTime)
    {
        systemDuration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(totalTime));
        masterStoryboard.Completed += new EventHandler(masterStoryboard_Completed);

    }

    void masterStoryboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        masterStoryboard.Children.Clear();
        //masterStoryboard.Completed -= masterStoryboard_Completed;
    }
 }
```

Once the compiler or program hits the line where the new EventHandler is created it stops executing the rest of my code and loads the window as is.  I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Is this the complete code from MovementTimeLine class?

Comment: Because it looks to me like you are adding an eventhandler without ever creating a StoryBoard object.

Comment: No it is not the complete MovementTimeLine Class the rest are just methods to adding and removing animations and are irrelevant to the constructor.  Wow I completely missed that.  Thank you so much for your help, that solved my problem.  How should I go about marking it as my answer?

Comment: @Core-One, please add an answer so that this question can be marked as answered.

Comment: @Wired365, you could have found that answer out yourself in a second if you had [debugged your program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/sc65sadd.aspx). I'd follow the link to find out how to do it if I were to .

Comment: @Sheridan The debugger didn't catch it and no errors were thrown.  I set multiple breakpoints and stepped through the code but it always got to the eventhandler line, stopped executing the rest of the code, and then loaded what it did have.  That's why I wasn't able to find the error before.  Everything before that line was fully functional.

Comment: Press `Ctrl+Alt+E` to open the Exception Window in Visual Studio and tick all of the User Handled tick boxes.

Comment: I think you mean user un-handled but those are already all checked.  Could it have anything to do with the fact that I am running Visual Studio Express and not the full version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks to me like you are adding an eventhandler without ever creating a StoryBoard object